# PHP/MySQL - Stopping Foreach Running The Same Query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

I've been trying to create a poll system which runs querys against a database and if it finds a match, doesn't include that answer.

It's a poll system that when the user votes on a poll, it stores the pollid and userid in a database table where it's then retrieved for when they re-visit the page so the poll they previously voted on isn't shown.

I will try my best to explain, i'm finding it very difficult to understand myself.

In my Pollsdone (Where the poll and the userid who completed the poll goes) table it contains 2 rows and 2 columns.

The two rows are:
pollid
userid

The two columns for pollsdone are (Userid doesn't matter):
26, USERID
76, USERID

SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Polls";
$completedVoteSearch = "SELECT * FROM Pollsdone WHERE userid='10'";
```

When i use:

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    foreach ($db->query($completedVoteSearch) as $done) {
       if ($done['pollid'] != $row['pollid']) {
         // CREATE POLL CODE
```

It will run a query against the database and correctly select which ones match. The problem is, it will also select ones like "44,76" and display the poll "76" even though it's a match with "76,76" 
Hopefully this photo helps you understand it better: (Not it says "We have a match!" and displays the poll still)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfTLS.png

It's still showing the poll even though it should be hidden because of other queries, how do i go about stopping this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code im using (Just for reference, there's not an error, it doesn't need to be 'debugged')

```
try {
                            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_db", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Polls";
                            $completedVoteSearch = "SELECT * FROM Pollsdone WHERE userid='10'";

                            foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
                                foreach ($db->query($completedVoteSearch) as $done) {
                                    if ($done['pollid'] == $row['pollid']) {
                                        echo "We have a match!";
                                    }
                                    if ($done['pollid'] != $row['pollid']) {
                                        echo "<br/>";
                                        echo $done['pollid'] . ", ";
                                        echo $row['pollid'] . ", ";
                                        echo "<br/>";
                                        $pollid = $row['pollid'];
                                        $title = $row['title'];
                                        $type = $row['type'];
                                            if ($type == "s") {
                                                $type = "radio";
                                            } else {
                                                $type = "checkbox";
                                            }

                                        $option1 = $row['option1'];
                                        $option2 = $row['option2'];
                                        $option3 = $row['option3'];
                                        $option4 = $row['option4'];
                                        $option5 = $row['option5'];
                                        $option6 = $row['option6'];

                                        $option1vote = $row['option1vote'];
                                        $option2vote = $row['option2vote'];
                                        $option3vote = $row['option3vote'];
                                        $option4vote = $row['option4vote'];
                                        $option5vote = $row['option5vote'];
                                        $option6vote = $row['option6vote'];

                                        $option1voteColumn = "option1vote";
                                        $option2voteColumn = "option2vote";
                                        $option3voteColumn = "option3vote";
                                        $option4voteColumn = "option4vote";
                                        $option5voteColumn = "option5vote";
                                        $option6voteColumn = "option6vote";
                                    }
                                }
                            // $isCompleteSQL = "SELECT * FROM Pollsdone WHERE userid='10' ";
                            // if ()

                            if (strlen($option3) < 1  && strlen($option2) > 0) {
                                echo '<div class="userPoll">
                                    <div class="pollTitle">
                                        <h3 class="pollHeader">' . $title . ' (ID = ' . $pollid . ')</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pollContent">
                                        <p class="pollSubTitle">Created By <a href="profile.php">Username</a></p>
                                        <form class="poll" method="POST" action="mypolls.php">
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'" value="option1vote"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option1 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'" value="option2vote"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option2 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <input type="submit" class="pollSubmit btn btn-default"/>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';

                                if ($_POST[$pollid] . $pollid == $option1voteColumn . $pollid) {
                                    $option1vote = ($option1vote + 1);                          
                                    $voteSQL = "UPDATE Polls SET ".$option1voteColumn."='".$option1vote."' WHERE pollid='".$pollid."'";
                                    $db->exec($voteSQL);
                                }
                            }

                            if (strlen($option4) < 1  && strlen($option3) > 0) {
                                echo '<div class="userPoll">
                                    <div class="pollTitle">
                                        <h3 class="pollHeader">' . $title . ' (ID = ' . $pollid . ')</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pollContent">
                                        <p class="pollSubTitle">Created By <a href="profile.php">Username</a></p>
                                        <form class="poll" method="POST" action="mypolls.php">
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option1 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option2 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option3 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <input type="submit" class="pollSubmit btn btn-default"/>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }

                            if (strlen($option5) < 1 && strlen($option4) > 0) {
                                echo '<div class="userPoll">
                                    <div class="pollTitle">
                                        <h3 class="pollHeader">' . $title . ' (ID = ' . $pollid . ')</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pollContent">
                                        <p class="pollSubTitle">Created By <a href="profile.php">Username</a></p>
                                        <form class="poll" method="POST" action="mypolls.php">
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option1 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option2 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option3 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option4 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <input type="submit" class="pollSubmit btn btn-default"/>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }

                            if (strlen($option6) < 1 && strlen($option5) > 0) {
                                echo '<div class="userPoll">
                                    <div class="pollTitle">
                                        <h3 class="pollHeader">' . $title . ' (ID = ' . $pollid . ')</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pollContent">
                                        <p class="pollSubTitle">Created By <a href="profile.php">Username</a></p>
                                        <form class="poll" method="POST" action="mypolls.php">
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option1 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option2 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option3 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option4 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option5 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <input type="submit" class="pollSubmit btn btn-default"/>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }

                            if (strlen($option6) > 0) {
                                echo '<div class="userPoll">
                                    <div class="pollTitle">
                                        <h3 class="pollHeader">' . $title . ' (ID = ' . $pollid . ')</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pollContent">
                                        <p class="pollSubTitle">Created By <a href="profile.php">Username</a></p>
                                        <form class="poll" method="POST" action="mypolls.php">
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option1 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option2 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option3 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option4 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option5 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <label><input type="' . $type . '" class="pollAnswer" name="'. $pollid .'"><p class="pollAnswerText">' . $option6 . '</p></label><br/>
                                            <input type="submit" class="pollSubmit btn btn-default"/>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                        }$db = null;

                        } catch(PDOException $e) {
                            $e->getMessage();
                        }
```

Comment: What is `44,76`, what is `76,76`? What is the main goal you try to achive? Not to show polls in which user already participated? `select * from Polls where pollid NOT IN (select pollid from polldone where user_id = 10)`

Comment: That might work. I'll try it and give it ago @U_mulder!

Comment: I'm then getting the error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [..loc..] on line 70 " The foreach is:                 `foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row)` with the SQL being: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Polls WHERE pollid NOT IN (SELECT pollid FROM Pollsdone WHERE userid = 10)";`

Comment: Nope sorry. I just copied your SQL wrong, it works PERFECTLY and uses ALOT less code. Create an answer and you'll be #1! :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I got you right, you're trying to select polls that user not participated yet.
You can use this query:

```
select * from `polls_table` 
where `pollid` NOT IN 
    (select `pollid` from `pollsdone` 
     where `user_id` = 10)
```